# issue updating facebook user status from my app

Tags: facebook, api, status

what permissions do i need for my facebook app to update status on user behalf.

I already have `publish_actions` and `publish_streams` permissions but still my app gives me an error:

> error 200: the user did not grant this app the required permissions.

Comment: Permissions you used are correct. Post the code where you have set the permissions for your application.

Comment: i've set permissions from facebook app settings, and facebook only takes permission for user basic info and friendlist, facebook doesnt ask user that my app may post of their behalf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions set in the App Settings are not applied to the app. They are used for logins triggered from the App Center by the `Play Game`/`Go to App` buttons – since that is a mechanism where you as the app developer don’t trigger/implement the login yourself, you can not set a scope parameter there; and therefore you make those settings in your app dashboard, so that Facebook knows what permissions to ask for when the user enters your app this way. - Info by *CBroe*.

For the permissions be applied in your app, you should set the permissions through your code. The permissions are set while implementing the `login` functionality. For eg: In Javascript, it is done like this: [FB.Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Comment: Thanks i did that and it works now but now the problem is, my app does not ask for permission the first time user logins...

Comment: Then when it asks for the permissions? PS. don't forget to accept the answer if worked! You can ask a separate question with your login code

Comment: When i ask permissions second time it works, but when i clear browser cache cookies etc it does not work...

Comment: _“They are just meant to remember what permissions you have used in your app”_ – that’s not correct. They _are_ used for logins triggered from the App Center by the “Play Game”/“Go to App” buttons – since that is a mechanism where you as the app developer don’t trigger/implement the login yourself, you can not set a `scope` parameter there; and therefor you make those settings in your app dashboard, so that Facebook knows what permissions to ask for when the user enters your app this way.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I'll update my answer. Thanks for the correction